# Unknown SyntaxError with Axios in my React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, material-ui

I am trying to make a call to my database with axios, and I get a frustrating error in my vsCode terminal.

Here's the error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Kelly Owoju\Desktop\Kelly Bright\my-web-app\node_modules\axios\index.js: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)

> 1 |                                         
    | ^
    at parser.next (<anonymous>
```

And here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { withStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Menu from '../component/Menu';
import Typer from '../component/Typed';
import Show from '../component/Show'
import axios from 'axios';
// import Boxes from '../component/Boxes'



const styles = theme => createStyles({
    avatar: {
        [theme.breakpoints.down('lg')]: {
            marginLeft: '150px'
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            marginLeft: '100px'
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            marginLeft: '100px'
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
            marginLeft: '20px'
        },
        width: '60px',
        height: '60px',
    },
    loading: {
        textAlign: 'center'
    }

})



class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            slides: null
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/slides').then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.setState({slides: res.data});
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        });
    };

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        let showSection = this.state.slides ? (
            this.state.slides.map(slide => <Show slide={slide} key={slide.id} />)
        ): <p className={classes.loading} >Loading...</p>
        return(
            <>
            <AppBar position='fixed' >
                <Toolbar>
                    <Avatar 
                    className={classes.avatar}
                    variant='circle'
                    src='logo.jpg'
                    />
                    <Menu />
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            {showSection}
            <Typer />
            </>           
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Home);
```

Please can someone help me out on this? I don't know what the issue might be. I haven't even seen this before. Who knows, it might even be something trivial. But please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with axios itself, try reinstalling the module:

`npm uninstall axios`

`npm install axios`

Comment: Whoa. This is the error I get while re-installing after uninstalling axios:

Comment: ? I dont think stackoverflow posted the rest of the comment.

Comment: npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Kelly Owoju\Desktop\Kelly Bright\my-web-app\node_modules\axios
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Kelly Owoju\Desktop\Kelly Bright\my-web-app\node_modules\.axios.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4048

I get these lines of errors and some more when I tried re-installing axios.
But the funniest thing is, axios is still in my package.json dependencies. How's this possible?

Comment: npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.


The remaining error lines..

Comment: @greg921. It eventually worked after several tries.. Uninstalled axios and re-installed it, then changed the import position to immediately after React import. Don't know why that worked, but it worked. Thank you.